# GROUP BY single column without doing raw sql

Tags: python, django

I want to do a simple `GROUP BY` statuement in django using a mysql backend (it doesn't support GROUP BY on a column in the django ORM). I usually use the following to do this:

```
Cue.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM main_cue GROUP BY group_id")
```

Is there a way to do this without using `.raw()` here? The equivalent of:

```
Cue.objects.values('*').distinct('group_id')
```

I am chaining filters here so I need to keep it 'within the ORM'.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @ruddra Mysql is the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best I have so far, but it's pretty unclean:

```
cues = self._get_assignable_cues(keyword)
group_ids = tuple(cues.values_list('group_id', flat=True).distinct())
cues_per_group = Cue.objects.raw(
    'SELECT * FROM main_cue WHERE group_id IN %s GROUP BY group_id', (group_ids,)
)
```